# Slim Application Error DB

Tags: php, rest, api, slim, slim-3

I'm newbie on Restful API's. I'm trying to make my own following internet tutorials.
 For this API i'm using Slim PHP Framework.

I've create my db.php (config file):

```
<?php
class db {
    //properties
    private $dbhost = 'localhost';
    private $dbuser = 'root';
    private $dbpass = '';
    private $dbname = 'slimapi';

    //Connect
    public function connect() {
        $mysql_connect_str = "mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname";
        $dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_connect_str, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $dbConnection;
    }
}
```

And then i've got my paciente.php (Where i'm trying to fetch de data to):

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

//Get All Pacientes
$app->get('/api/pacientes', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pacientes";

    try {
        //GET DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $pacientes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJECT);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($pacientes);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

**I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHqME.jpg) error when i try to load /api/pacientes:**

> Slim Application Error
>   A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.

*I've already tested the connection with the DB and it's ok.* I might be doing something wrong on the config file (db.php) but idk.
 ***Thank you to everyone for reading and answering!***

EDIT: 
 Add my index.php if needed:

```
    <?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../src/config/db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});

//Pacientes Routes
require '../src/routes/pacientes.php';

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo: 
 Line 18 on pacientes.php

```
    $pacientes = $stmt->fetchAll(**PDO::FETCH_OBJECT**);
```

**MUST BE**

```
    $pacientes = $stmt->fetchAll(***PDO::FETCH_OBJ***);
```